# How to load categorical attributes in scikit-learn?

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I want to create a Bayes model in scikit-learn to predict box office openings for movies.

I'm starting with scikit learn and I found many examples on how to load CSV and other table data, but I haven't found examples on how to load attributes with a collection of values, e.g:

```
Movie 1: Actors: [Actor 1, Actor 2, Actor 3...], etc.
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) is the preferred way of handling categorical data that is not already encoded as a Numpy array. For each sample, you can build a bunch of dicts that looks like

```
[{'Tom Hanks': True, 'Halle Berry': True},
 {'Tom Hanks': True, 'Kevin Bacon': True}]
```

etc. The keys must be strings; the values may be either strings (which are expanded using a one-of-k coding), booleans or numbers. `DictVectorizer` then transforms these dicts to a matrix that can be fed to a learning algorithm. The matrix will have one column per actor (or other movie feature) in the entire input set. Features not occurring in a dict/sample have an implicit value of zero.

Comment: One problem with this representation is that it's going to be extremely high dimensional. Depending on the learning algorithm, it might be helpful to reduce the dimensionality of these features using e.g. PCA.

Comment: @Dougal: simple feature selection (using an L1-penalized SVM or `SelectKBest(chi2)`) is easier to handle than PCA, in my experience. The result is also easier to interpret because the features retain their names, and `DictVectorizer` has support for feature selection in its `restrict` method.

Comment: Agreed - but, since I'd expect there to be a lot of covariance structure in the actors who are in various movies, a PCA-type approach may be more informative. Worth trying both.